# Questions including "do you think"

Tags: word-order, parenthesis

> 1. Why do you think the painter left the palace?
> 2. Why, do you think, the painter left the palace?

Does anyone feel an ambiguity in question 1?

I feel that the question word *why* can either be applied to 'thinking' (*Why do you think?*) or to 'leaving' (*Why the painter left the palace?*)

Shouldn't the clause *do you think* be parenthetical as in question 2, to avoid the ambiguity?

When the clause *do you think* is separated by commas, is the inversion needed as in question 3 below?

> 3. Why, do you think, did the painter leave the palace?

Comment: For what it’s worth, I didn’t even notice the ambiguity until I reread your question. I read (1) as a request for speculation about the painter’s motivation. For the other meaning, I would have asked something like “What makes you think the painter left the palace?”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I encounter  a sentence such as:

> Why do you think the painter left the palace?

I would always read it as meaning

> Why, in your opinion, did the painter leave the palace.

unless there was context clearly indicating another meaning.

If I wanted to ask about the reason for a belief, I might say something like:

> What makes you think that the painter left the palace.

Or one could add context:

> Why do you think the painter left the palace? Perhaps he is still in the inner court.

In some cases the subject of the query gives the contest:

> Why do you think that two plus two makes five?

While one could use commas, as:

> Why, do you think, the painter left the palace?

to me this seems awkward and pedantic, and I would not think the meaning changed merely by the presence or absence of such commas. Something clearer would be needed.